# How to add image background to btn-default twitter-bootstrap button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to design a bootstrap v3.3.5 button by using the existing class **btn-default**, below are the sample of codes of what I had done.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
  .sign-in-facebook
  {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png');
    background-position: -9px -7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    color: #000;
  }
  .sign-in-facebook:hover
  {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png');
    background-position: -9px -7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    color: #000;
  }
</style>
<p>My current button got white background<br/>
<input type="button" value="Sign In with Facebook" class="btn btn-default sign-in-facebook" style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;" >
</p>
<p>I need the current btn-default style like below<br/>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Sign In with Facebook" />
</p>
<strong>NOTE:</strong> facebook icon at left side of the button.
```

Sample facebook icon:

[image: Sample fb-icon]

How I can modify the class of `.sign-in-facebook` to create my own style button ?

Answer (score 51):

Instead of using `input type button` you can use `button` and insert the image inside the button content.

```
<button class="btn btn-default">
     <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png" width="20" /> Sign In with Facebook
</button>
```

The problem with doing this only with CSS is that you cannot set `linear-gradient` to the background you must use solid color.

```
.sign-in-facebook {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png') #f2f2f2;
    background-position: -9px -7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    color: #000;
  }
  .sign-in-facebook:hover {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png') #e0e0e0;
    background-position: -9px -7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    color: #000;
  }
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  .sign-in-facebook {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png') #f2f2f2;
    background-position: -9px -7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    color: #000;
  }
  .sign-in-facebook:hover {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png') #e0e0e0;
    background-position: -9px -7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    color: #000;
  }
</style>


<h4>Only with CSS</h4>

<input type="button" value="Sign In with Facebook" class="btn btn-default sign-in-facebook" style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;">

<h4>Only with HTML</h4>

<button class="btn btn-default">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png" width="20" /> Sign In with Facebook
</button>
```

Comment: @wazaaaap he wants to do it with css only so he doesnt have to add the <img> element to the button manualy.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using a icon font like http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Bootstrap comes with their own library, but it doesn't have as many icons as Font Awesome.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Answer (score 4):

This works with font awesome:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-success">
   <i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   Print
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
  .sign-in-facebook
  {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png');
    background-position: -9px -7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    color: #000;
  }
  .sign-in-facebook:hover
  {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2S63.png');
    background-position: -9px -7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    color: #000;
  }
</style>
<p>My current button got white background<br/>
<input type="button" value="Sign In with Facebook" class="sign-in-facebook btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;" >
</p>
<p>I need the current btn-default style like below<br/>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Sign In with Facebook" />
</p>
<strong>NOTE:</strong> facebook icon at left side of the button.
```