# How to make a button with an image background?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I want to make an *image button* i.e. the button should have:

- an image background
- The button should have a custom translucent dark overlay that lightens on hover and becomes even darker on click.
- fixed height (of 300px), and width 100% (so that it occupies the entire parent `div class="col-md-4"`).
- The image should be `cropped` i.e. `overflow: hidden`

I tried to achieve this by setting the image as background to my parent `<div>` and used a child `<div>` for the translucent overlays. But I had to write a lot of jquery to change the states onhover, onclick, etc.

I realized I should be using a button, and not a div but I could not style it and make it overlay the parent div.

Current code:

HTML element:

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="background-image: url('...'); overflow: hidden; height: 200px; margin-bottom: 24px">
  <div class="img-panel translucent-overlay-light"> <!-- Should be a button or a tag -->
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript: (ideally there should be no js, all this should be done in CSS)

```
$('.img-panel').click(function() {
    // do something
});

$('.img-panel').mouseenter(function() {
    var elm = $(this);
    elm.removeClass('translucent-overlay-light');
    elm.addClass('translucent-overlay-dark')
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var elm = $(this);
    elm.removeClass('translucent-overlay-dark');
    elm.addClass('translucent-overlay-light')
});
```

Also, I am using SCSS anyway so both SCSS and CSS answers are fine.

Comment: Could you please mention the size of your button.

Comment: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281792/how-to-add-image-background-to-btn-default-twitter-bootstrap-button) check this out...................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS only with `pseudo-elements`. Hope that works for you.

```css
.col{
  width:50%;
  display:block;
}

.img-panel{
  position:relative;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any');
  background-size:cover;
  color:white;
}

.img-panel:after{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  transition:0.2s;
}

.img-panel:hover:after{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) ;
}

.img-panel:active:after{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) ;
}
```

```html
<div class="col col-md-4">
  <div class="img-panel translucent-overlay-light">
        Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not hard, just using css:

```css
.my-button {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&bg=22ffdd&txtclr=000000&txt=&w=250&h=250');
}
.my-button::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.my-button:hover::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.my-button:active::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-button">
    Click me
</div>
```

You just may need to adjust background image size and position, [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images).

Comment: Wow this is nice. But I want a `button` instead of a `div`. I just changed that in your code and the button shrinked to wrap the text :(

Comment: If you use a button, than you have to remove default browser styles, which are different for FF, Chrome and others.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need something like that, please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/js00evnk/1/). It's pure CSS solution.

```css
.btn-wrap {
  .btn-wrap__input {
     width: 100%;
     height: 300px;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 3;
     margin: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     &:checked {
       + .btn-wrap__overlay {
         opacity: .7;
       }
       &:hover {
         + .btn-wrap__overlay {
           opacity: .7;
         }  
       }
     }
     &:hover {
      + .btn-wrap__overlay {
         opacity: .5;
       }
    }
  }
  .btn-wrap__button {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .btn-wrap__back {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT7ixV_dB22rsPTNwbph6uHl62bSSNHK_TQLw1gMOPmoWErkRdK');
    
  }
  .btn-wrap__overlay {
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 btn-wrap">
  <div class='btn-wrap__button'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='btn-wrap__input'>
    <div class="btn-wrap__overlay"></div>
    <div class="btn-wrap__back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is some checkbox. The other answers actually achieve what I want